# stream data from flume to collect data from different directories

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, flume

the logs from different netwok devices are getting uploaded in different directory structure /appdat/logs/device//devicename.gzip. So all the devices will store their logs in respective ZIP code dir.Can any existing flume source be used to send the new uploaded file on any of the sub-directory to HDFS or do i need to write a new custom source.the cloudera version being used is cdh4

Answer (score 0):

There is a change proposed by Phil Scala that will do recursive checking. To my knowledge it hasn't been accepted yet.

The current actively developed version is Apache Flume - not the Cloudera version.

Comment: thanks for the reply in which version of flume is this available .its fine if its not packaged in cloudera deployment

Comment: It's a patch against Flume 1.4 in [FLUME-1899](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-1899).